# Wrong common expression substitution in C compiler?

Tags: pointers, gcc, compiler-construction

```
double *p;
```

Apparently, gcc 4.6.3 only increments `p` by 1 in the following line under `-O3`.

```
myfunc (*(p++), *(p++));
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: You might want to search for the term "sequence point."  This is a common question about the increment operators and I think that you can find some really good answers if you search the site.

Comment: One operation per line of code is the way to go - you make the code easier to read and will not suffer from these sort of problems.

Comment: @EdHeal +1 for 'one operation per line of code is the way to go'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

Comment: ProTip: **it's almost NEVER a compiler bug.**

Answer (score 1):

`*(p++)` doesn't increment the value that pointer points to.

if you want the value incremented you would do `(*p)++` ;

Another thing is, you aren't guaranteed the order in which parameters are evaluated. It depends on the compiler. So the left side could be incremented first, it could be incremented second. Regardless one parameter will be sent in with the original value and the next will be the original value + 1 (due to the nature of the post increment);
Outside the function, if you didn't modify *p inside it, the *p should have been incremented twice.

Answer (score 1):

Increment operators cause undefined behavior if they modify the `same variable` in the `same sequence point (statement)`. 
For example if you call a function like this:

```
foo(++i, ++i)
```

The C standard doesn't say in which order the increments should be performed, and you can't predict what will be passed to the function.
Its the same case with your function.

> `myfunc (*(p++), *(p++))`

Either of them can evaluate first.